# Merge two columns into one, element by element in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(estimate = c(1,2), sd = c("(0.5)*","(0.5)***"))
rownames(df) <- c("race","gender")
```

I want to make a journal quality table by merging the two columns into one, element by element. The desired output would be:

```
         Results  
race     1
         (0.5)*
gender   2
         (0.5)***
```

Comment: try `m1 <- matrix(c(t(df)));row.names(m1) <- c(rbind(row.names(df), ""))`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for such a beautiful solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `data.frame` cannot have duplicate rownames, it may be better to store it in a `matrix`.  We get the transpose (`t`) of the dataset, create a `matrix` with single column and assign the row names by `rbind`ing the existing row names of the original dataset with the blank (`""`)

```
m1 <- matrix(c(t(df)), dimnames = list(c(rbind(row.names(df), "")), "Results"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R approach using `lapply`, `t`, `do.call` and [**`noquote`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/noquote):

```
out <- noquote(do.call('rbind',lapply(1:dim(df)[1],function(x) t(df[x,]))))
  attr(out,'dimnames') <- list(c(rbind(row.names(df),"")),'Results')

       Results 
race   1       
       (0.5)*  
gender 2       
       (0.5)***
```

**Update**:

@akrun's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51119741/4581200) is much neater than mine, but his resulting matrix elements are all in quotes! Combine the **`noquote()`** function from my answer to his, and you've got exactly what you're looking for!

```
 noquote(matrix(c(t(df)), dimnames = list(c(rbind(row.names(df), "")), "Results")))
```